Maven build fails due to Keystore access
I'm trying to do a maven clean build but my build keeps failing. It appears that mvn can't access the cacerts file but I haven't changed the default password, does anyone know what I can try to fix this issue?  I'm getting this output:
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:3.4.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed


" does anyone know what I can try to fix this issue?" - Scan for malware? If the trust store gets tampered with and you didn't do anything, that is pretty suspicious. But ultimately it would boil down to reinstalling Java I guess.

Your interpretation of that error looks faulty. Better post the full trace

Which Maven version do you use? And which JDK version do you use?

I needed to add an extra SSL cert and I had setup maven to look in another file which was causing issues.
